# Javascript/Ember - Toggle Boolean Value of Variable

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, boolean, toggle

I know that there is the .set() method to set a boolean to true or false but I want to know if there a method like .set() except it Toggles the value of a boolean.

In this case the boolean isEditing is being set to 'true'.

```
isEditing:false,
actions: {
  edit: function(category){
    category.set('isEditing', true);
    console.log(this.get('isEditing'))
  },
}
```

Here is the html

```
{{#if isEditing}}
  <div class="category-text"> 
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=name action="turnOffEditMode"}}
  </div>
{{else}}
  <div class="category-text"> 
    {{#linkTo 'category' this}}
      {{name}}
    {{/linkTo}}
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
this.toggleProperty('propertyName');
```

Edit:  [jsbin for proof](http://jsbin.com/reboq/2/)

Comment: Thank you, gravity. This was what I was looking for, but Rajesh's solution worked as well

Comment: This is the most succinct method.

Comment: He asked if there was a method other than `set` and this is that method. Sorry.

Comment: Toggle Boolean Value of Variable what does this mean ?

Comment: "I want to know if there a method like .set() except it Toggles the value of a boolean"

Comment: can you define the method here ?

Comment: both solutions are setting isEditing to false I just discovered through console.log. Strangely enough, the content between {{#if isEditing}} and {{else}} is still displaying as if isEditing were true. The weirdest part is that when i use .set to only make isEditing true, it does become true, but the {{#if isEditing}} does not display the code between {{#if isEditing}} and {{else}} anymore. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 4):

```
isEditing:false,
actions: {
    edit: function(category){
        category.set('isEditing', !category.isEditing);
        console.log(this.get('isEditing'))
    }
    toggleEditing : function(category){
    }
}
```

Toggling the boolean value is what you need. Or yu can change your function like below.

```
isEditing:false,
actions: {
    toggleEditing : function(category){
        category.set('isEditing', !category.isEditing);
        console.log(this.get('isEditing'));
    }
}
```

Comment: category.set('isEditing', !isEditing);  results in "Uncaught ReferenceError: isEditing is not defined "

Comment: Why this got down voted ? Would be great if you could provide a reason

Comment: I voted this and your previous comment UP. I don't have enough rep to vote down. To reiterate to the haters, THIS SOLUTION WORKED. ;)

Comment: this.toggleProperty is better for this cases. I think the answer from @gravityplanx is better.

Comment: Also if you were going to do it explicitly, you need to use get instead of getting the value directly `category.set('isEditing', !category.get('isEditing'))`

Answer (score 1):

@gravityplanx's answer is great.

I just want to add that this methodology works beyond the controller as well.

For example, if my Model has a `Post` object, I can update it from the controller. I just have to pass the object into a controller action.

```
switch_readiness(post) {
    post.toggleProperty('isPublishReady');
}
```

Comment: `toggleFood(food) { food.toggleProperty('available') }`  - doesn't really work for me... seems like @gravityplanx picked out one small part of the question and answered it - but not in the context.